# Do I need to add the same reference in two projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Since I'm new to the .NET development I think this is a concept problem.

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1. **Foo.Core:** a class library that references Fluent NHibernate, NHibernate and Npgsql. This is my business layer with services, entities and NHibernate mappings.
2. **Foo.Core.Tests:** a class library with tests that references NUnit and **Foo.Core**;
3. **Foo.MVC:** an MVC application that references just **Foo.Core**;

In **Foo.Core** I have a `FooService` with a `GetFoo` method that returns a `Foo` (entity) instance from database.

In MVC project I create an instance of `FooService` and call `GetFoo`, but it raises an exception that the NpgsqlDriver instance could not be created. If I add a reference to Npgsql, it works.

**Foo.Core** already **has** a reference to the driver and the connection is opened there. Why do I need to reference the driver, again, in the MVC project?

**Edit**

After more searching I found [this link](http://pgfoundry.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=10544&forum_id=519). The build ignores *Copy Local* if it's referenced is in GAC, but I checked and Npgsql.dll isn't registered there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have set "Copy Local" to `true` on the reference to Npgsql in Foo.Core (select the reference in the solution explorer, then click F4 to see the properties).

If set to true, you won't need to add the reference in Foo.MVC.

Comment: Yes, Npgsql's "Copy Local" is set to `true`, although Npgsql.dll isn't being copied to the `/bin` folder of the MVC project. What can cause this?